# Efficiently structure data into series by ID

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, hashmap, time-complexity

I am looking at a very large structured dataset that I would like to make unstructured. Here is the example…

```
x1  x2  x3  day  id  
1   5   9   2    A
9   7   9   3    B
3   1   4   1    A
2   6   5   1    B
3   5   8   2    B
3   2   3   2    C
```

The rows above are presented in a random order. Another way to think of this example is as follows…

```
x = [[1, 5, 9, 2, “A”],
     [9, 7, 9, 3, “B”],
     [3, 1, 4, 1, “A”],
     [2, 6, 5, 1, “B”],
     [3, 5, 8, 2, “B”],
     [3, 2, 3, 2, “C”]]
```

Once processed, the desired output is…

```
[[[3, 1, 4, 1], [1, 5, 9, 2]],
 [[2, 6, 5, 1], [3, 5, 8, 2], [9, 7, 9, 3]],
 [[3, 2, 3, 2]]],
[[1, A], [1,B], [2,C]]
```

The first list has the x variables, and the second list has the start date with each identifier.

I have an idea of how to achieve this, but it is in O(n^3). Is there a more efficient method, maybe in O(nlogn)?

Edit: Although mentioned in my previous post, I have made it clearer that the rows are presented in random order. I have also removed redundant column in the code example.

Comment: Why `[1, A], [1,B], [2,C]`? From where the integers come from?

Comment: @AndrejKesely From "day", check the first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = [
    [3, 1, 4, 1, 1, "A"],
    [1, 5, 9, 2, 2, "A"],
    [2, 6, 5, 1, 1, "B"],
    [3, 5, 8, 2, 2, "B"],
    [9, 7, 9, 3, 3, "B"],
    [3, 2, 3, 2, 2, "C"],
]


out = {}
for row in x:
    out.setdefault(row[-1], []).append(row[:-1])

print(list(out.values()) + [[[v[0][-1], k] for k, v in out.items()]])
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [[3, 1, 4, 1, 1], [1, 5, 9, 2, 2]],
    [[2, 6, 5, 1, 1], [3, 5, 8, 2, 2], [9, 7, 9, 3, 3]],
    [[3, 2, 3, 2, 2]],
    [[1, "A"], [1, "B"], [2, "C"]],
]
```

Comment: This might work if I first sort my data. I will need to check if sorting is viable given how large the data is.